# What does this "all*.exclude" means in Gradle transitive dependency?

Tags: gradle, transitive-dependency

I wonder what does "all*.exclude" mean in Gradle transitive dependency ?

```
configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
        all*.exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-all'
    }
```

Is "all*.exclude" in the code above syntax of Gradle or some else.

Comment: Have a look at this page : http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/10/gradle-goodness-exclude-transitive.html

Comment: what I really want to know is what "all*" stand for ?  Is that  some syntax in Gradle or   Groovy?

Comment: Tanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't visit it, maybe in China.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, `all*.` refers to all `configurations` ...

and it applies `exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-all'` to all of them.

The `all*.` syntax is the short-handed notation of:

```
configurations {
    all.collect { configuration ->
        configuration.exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-all'
    }
}
```

The `*.` syntax is called "spread-dot operator", which is a [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html) syntax (see paragraph `8.1`).

Comment: I get it. Thanks very much.