# What's the different between all*.exclude and all.exclude in configurations.all

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I want to know what exactly different between all*.exclude and all.exclude in configurations.all when you want to exclude dependencies

```
configurations.all {
    all.exclude
    all*.exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441430/what-does-this-all-exclude-means-in-gradle-transitive-dependency

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

### Using the `all` method

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

OR

### Using the `all` property

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude(group: 'org.json', module: 'json')
}
```

The `all` property holds a list of all [**`configuration`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) objects within the project [**`configurations`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:configurations).

If you want to see what it actually it contains you can do:

```
println configurations.all.names
```

OR

```
println configurations.all*.name
```

And the syntax `*.` is a groovy specific operator called the [spread operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_spread_operator). You can read how that works to understand why it worked here.