# Gradle groovy syntax "configurations {all*.exclude ...}"

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I came across Gradle Groovy DSL snippet like below:

```
configurations {
  all*.exclude group:'org.apache.hadoop', module:'hadoop-core'
}
```

The `all*.exclude` confused me totally. Is the above block equivalent to below?

```
configurations {
  all {
    exclude group:'org.apache.hadoop', module:'hadoop-core'
  }
}
```

Also, is there a reference that explains the `all*.exclude` syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is indeed the same.

`all` is a property containing a list with all the configuration objects. The `*.` part is Groovy syntax, meaning "execute the action on each element of the list". It's called *[spread operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator)*.

The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57506009/whats-the-different-between-all-exclude-and-all-exclude-in-configurations-all).

Answer (score 0):

We can exclude transitive dependencies easily from specific configurations. To exclude them from all configurations we can use Groovy's spread-dot operator and invoke the exclude() method on each configuration. We can only define the group, module or both as arguments for the exclude() method.

```
configurations {
all*.exclude group:'org.apache.hadoop', module:'hadoop-core'
```

}

Equivalent to :

```
configurations {
all.collect { configuration ->
    configuration.exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-core'
}
```

}