# How to exclude library from dependencies?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, dependency-management

I have a gradle project with several modules in it. In the main module I have `id "io.spring.dependency-management"` plugin. In the `adapters` module I have dependency on the main one `implementation project(":main")` with `runtimeOnly 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql` in dependency block, which pulls `0.8.12.RELEASE` version of the `r2dc-postgresql` driver.

Now I want to use `0.8.13.RELEASE` verision of the driver, so I simply added `runtimeOnly 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:0.8.13.RELEASE` to the dependency declaration, but now I have two versions of this library in external libraries section (`0.8.12.RELEASE` and `0.8.13.RELEASE`), but  `./gradlew adapters:dependencies` displays only `0.8.13.RELEASE` version.

How to find out where `0.8.12.RELEASE` is coming from now and remove it?

I tried

```
exlude(group = 'io.r2dbc', module =  'r2dbc-postgresql')
```

but it didn't work

Comment: it seems when i declare the dependency in the main module, Gradle resolves them properly, only `0.8.13:RELEASE` is shown in external libraries section. But I want to declare it in the `adapters` module anyway...

Answer (score 0):

have you had a look at e.g.:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html

or

[How to exclude library from all dependencies in Kotlin DSL build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375085/how-to-exclude-library-from-all-dependencies-in-kotlin-dsl-build-gradle)

or

[What does this "all*.exclude" means in Gradle transitive dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441430/what-does-this-all-exclude-means-in-gradle-transitive-dependency)

Comment: yes, I've tried to exclude dependency, but it removes dependency at all, you cannot specify which version you want to remove

Comment: it seems when i declare the dependency in the main module, Gradle resolves them properly, only `0.8.13:RELEASE` is shown in external libraries section. But I want to declare it in the `adapters` module anyway..